# Exporting struct template instantiation to C code from inside C++ library

Tags: c++, c, templates, shared-libraries

When mixing C and C++, with C++ being a lib and C the main app, I can do following:

```
// lib.h
#pragma once

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

#include "stdint.h"

void fooInt(int val);
void fooFloat(float val);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

and cpp file:

```
// lib.cpp
#include "lib.h"
#include <iostream> 
#include <typeinfo>

template <typename T>
void foo(T val) {
    std::cout << typeid(val).name() << std::endl;
}

void fooInt(int val) {
    foo(val);
}

void fooFloat(float val) {
    foo(val);
}
```

Which allows me to generate a number of c function based on template. But I wonder is there a way to do the same for structs?

header:

```
#pragma once

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

#include "stdint.h"

struct COptionalUint16_t;

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

source file

```
#include "lib.h"
#include <iostream> 
#include <typeinfo>

template <typename T>
struct COptional{
    T value;
    bool isSet;
};

using COptionalUint16_t = COptional<uint16_t>;
```

Obviously, the last example does not work. Maybe someone could suggest the way around that?

Comment: `struct COptionalUint16_t;` is an incomplete type. As long as the C code only has a pointer to the struct, and doesn't need to access the members, that's fine. Otherwise, it's no deal. There's no way around it (using templates).

Comment: Of course, you can always abuse the C preprocessor to emulate template behavior. In that case, the header file is pure C, and is included in both the C source and the C++ source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing can be done like with the functions. You can do

```
#pragma once

#ifdef __cplusplus

#include <cstdint>

template <typename T>
struct COptional {
    T value;
    bool isSet;
};

using COptionalUint16_t = COptional<uint16_t>;

#else

#include <stdint.h>

typedef struct {
    uint16_t value;
    bool isSet;
} COptionalUint16_t;

#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of 'using' try typedef like this.

typedef COptional<uint16_t> myCoptional_uint16;

then in the c code

myCoptional_uint16 myInstance;